Did B2C user creation defaults change regarding password reset?
I have a site where external users sign in using a B2C tenant with custom policies. The site has been up and running for a few years without issue. Recently users newly created in the Azure portal UI aren't able to login using the initial password. They just get the "Your password has expired" error message on the login screen.
If I create a new B2C user via the graph API and set forceChangePasswordNextSignIn=false, the user is able to sign in as expected.
Can anyone confirm that the B2C user creation behavior in the Azure portal has changed? Is it possible to change it back somehow?

There may have been changes made to your custom policies or other configurations causing the issue. Check this link and try again to implement the flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-change-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow#set-up-password-change-by-using-custom-policies-in-azure-active-directory-b2c

I've spoken with Microsoft support and supposedly they are rolling out a fix for this issue.

Microsoft released a fix and I can confirmed that it's working as usual again.

Initially, I created one internal user in my B2C tenant via Portal like this:

When I tried to login with this new user initial password, I too got same error as below:


This is currently a bug and Microsoft team is working on rolling out a fix for this issue as you mentioned in comments.

Now, I created one external user in my B2C tenant via Portal like this:

When I tried to login with this new external user initial password, it worked and user logged in successfully as below:

As an alternative, you can either go with this external user creation or create B2C users via Graph API till the bug resolves.

This issue was always about external users, you must have tested just after the fixed it.
